# R levelplot: How to shade some pixels out to show statistical significance

Tags: r, levelplot

I am posting this also on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151884/r-levelplot-how-to-shade-some-pixels-out-to-show-statistical-significance) because the topic is in the middle between `GIS` and `R` programming.

I need to include statistical significance in a map in R using `rasteVis`, which is based on `levelplot`.

Using the example from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569666/showing-data-values-on-levelplot-in-r), I can write some text on each of the cells, or on a selection of those, as for instance:

```
library("lattice")
x <- seq(pi/4, 5*pi, length.out=10)
y <- seq(pi/4, 5*pi, length.out=10)
r <- as.vector(sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+")))
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
grid$z <- cos(r^2)*exp(-r/(pi^3))

p <- levelplot(z~x*y, grid, 
               panel=function(...) {
                 arg <- list(...)
                 panel.levelplot(...)
                 panel.text(arg$x, arg$y, ifelse(arg$z>=0,round(arg$z,1),""))})
print(p)
```

[image]

Instead of writing something, how can I shade out these pixels (using for instance light grey lines)? 
Should I overlay a second raster?

Comment: Could you set the data to `NA` and colour `NA` cells gray?

Comment: I want the background color to be evident. Even if the values are not significant at cell level, the visualization of the variation trend for the domain under investigation is relevant.

Comment: I don't follow you. Do you want the cells coloured but *also* "shaded out"?

Comment: exactly. see this for instance https://19january2017snapshot.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2016-07/globalprecipmap-large.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any really easy way to add hatching-line graphics to a lattice graphics plot. With base graphics:

```
plot(0:1,0:1);polygon(x=c(0,.5,.5,.0),y=c(.2,.2,.6,.6),density=5)
```

will plot two points and draw a hatched polygon. But the corresponding lattice graphics function:

```
xyplot(x~y, data=data.frame(x=0:1,y=0:1),
  panel=function(...){panel.xyplot(...);panel.rect(0,.2,.5,.6,density=5)}
)
```

just draws the outline. The density is ignored and no shading lines are drawn.

Since lattice graphics do not use the underlying base graphics coordinate system it is hard to mix base graphics functions with lattice ones.

So you could do this using the base plotting functions for rasters. If anyone *can* do this with lattice, I'll be interested to see the methods in a new answer.

If using base graphics methods are acceptable, then add a comment and I'll have a go.

Comment: Hi @Spacedman, thanks for your try. I finally found a turnaround, by transforming all the data in raster and plotting using something like: `levelplot(background.info)+layer(sp.points(non_significant_cells, pch=7, cex=2, col="grey", alpha=0.5)` in this way I added a series of semi-transparent pch=7 symbols (http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-plot-pch-symbols-the-different-point-shapes-available-in-r) over the cells that were not statistically significant at the level I chose.